# "Requested entity was not found" when writing on Google Home Graph

Tags: google-home

I'm trying to update the state of a device using Google Home Graph API, but I'm getting this reply and I don't understand why:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
```

This is the first part of my `SYNC` reponse:

```
{
    "requestId": "reqId",
    "payload": {
        "agentUserId": "myAgentUserId",
        "devices": [
            {
                "id": "myDeviceId",
...
}
```

and this is what I'm sending to

> https://homegraph.googleapis.com/v1/devices:reportStateAndNotification

```
{
    "agentUserId": "myAgentUserId",
    "payload": {
        "devices": {
            "states": {
                "myDeviceId": {
                    "on": true
...
}
```

As you can see, both `myAgentUserId` and `myDeviceId` in Home Graph's request are the same to the ones returned to the `SYNC` request.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: were you able to get this working? facing same issue

Comment: same issue... any luck?